# What does []{return i == 1;} mean and how does it work in std wait and condition variables?

Tags: c++, mutex, condition-variable

From: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/condition_variable/wait

```
void waits()
{
    std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lk(cv_m);
    std::cerr << "Waiting... \n";
    cv.wait(lk, []{return i == 1;});
    std::cerr << "...finished waiting. i == 1\n";
}
```

Second argument is a predicate:

```
template< class Predicate >
void wait( std::unique_lock<std::mutex>& lock, Predicate pred );
```

What is that `[]` with doing there? How is writing that condition `i == 1` inside `wait` different from this:

```
if (i == 1)
{
    std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lk( mutex_association );
    // Do something with `i`
}
else
{
    std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lk( mutex_association );
    cv_association.wait( lk );
}
```

Comment: I'm sure there are duplicates, but before anyone find them read about [*lambda expressions*](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda).

Comment: Your initial `(i == 1)` check in your prospect equivalence is not protected under the mutex. It is in the lambda case (as it should be if it is part of your predicate data, and it certainly appears that is the case).